# IE Compatibility (Browser) Mode vs Doc Mode

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, web-development

So my understanding of [this Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode/), webpage is that there is a clear difference between browser (or compatibility) mode vs doc mode.

So is it a possible that a website that isn't compatible with IE 11, even with compatibility mode set to IE 9, could be "made" compatible by changing the doc mode of the IE browser to force Trident to render the page differently?